# docker compose php application from image

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm fairly new to docker and trying to understand a few things about it.

Here's my scenario, I want to have my application in it's own image and then use docker compose to blend it together (since I've read that you shouldn't be mixing nginx & php together, according to best practices).

I made a small PoC and so far it's not working, but I'm hoping it's just more me missing something important.

when I type in `docker-compose up`, everything loads but nginx seems to not know anything about the php service as it just loads the default nginx page and trying to access any php code from the php service gives me a 404.

this is what my compose yaml file looks like:

```yaml
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:mainline-alpine
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    php:
        image: myprivaterepo.com/poc/php-test:latest
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
```

and the dockerfile is currently simply:

```
FROM php:fpm

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

the idea is the php service has the php code and the web service would be able to access the files and it'd work.

I'm fairly sure I'm just missing something important but since I'm still new to this, I'm not sure what that is.

The goal would be to have the application all packed up and just spin up without a lot of hassle.

Comment: is that all in your compose.yml file?

Comment: yes, for now, once I have a working PoC I'll add onto it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do for docker is

First Dockerfile with everything I need; change docker file as you desire.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Create mysql folder in root and my.cnf in that directory with the following content

```
[mysqld]
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
```

Now create nginx/conf.d folder with app.conf with the following

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Now just create php/local.ini folder and leave it as it is for now

Now create docker-compose.yml file with following

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app-docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini`
    networks:
      - projectdocker

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "444:444"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - projectdocker

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    ports:
      - "6001:3306"
    container_name: db-docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - projectdocker

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    links:
      - db:db-docker
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - projectdocker

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  projectdocker:
    driver: bridge
```

now run `docker-compose up -d –build`

link to localhost will be `http://localhost:8081/`

link to phpmyadmin will be `http://localhost:7000/`